# Create table with calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, calculated-columns, create-table

I want to create table with three columns:

```
START_DATE|END_DATE|TOTAL_TIME
```

`START_DATE` and `END_DATE` should both be `date`s.
`TOTAL_TIME` should be calculated by using these two columns. How can I create the table?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a calculated column using the `as` keyword. Subtracting two `date`s in Oracle will give you the difference in days. You could then easily convert it to any unit you wish (e.g., multiply by 24 to get the duration in hours):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    total_time NUMBER AS (end_date - start_date) -- This is in days
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  Actually i want to get total_time=start_date-end_date . I want to get difference between these two columns in the third column. How to do that?

Comment: @kkl Just flip it around :-) Note, though, that `start_date-end_date` will always be negative

Comment: Hi my END_DATE column has a value like 2017-07-09 10:30:00 and START_DATE has value like 2017-07-09 09:30:00. I want to deduct START_DATE from END-DATE and get result as 1.30 (hrs) in the TOTAL_TIME. How to get this result?